# Is there any way to cast non-cantrip spells without taking a level in a spellcasting class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, feats, skills, magic

Can a Fighter learn spells and cast them without multiclassing?
I know of feats in supplement books that allow characters to learn and cast 1 cantrip ( lvl 0 spell).
I was wondering if there is either a feat or a rule that allows arcane training without multiclassing.

Like a character being a Fighter with the ability to cast one 1st Level spell...or even to have a spell list.

Answer (score 10):

Strictly speaking, *yes*, but it involves intense shenanigans.

First, the Magical Training feat from *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* gets you in the door with three cantrips from the Sor/Wiz list, cast as sorcerer or wizard would (your choice). You count as a spellcaster with caster level 1st (minimum). You must be an elf or human, and must be from a specific region of Faerûn (though this requirement ought to be waived or adapted if not playing in the Forgotten Realms).

From there, there are tricks to improve your spellcasting:

- Precocious Apprentice from *Complete Arcane* pg. 181 (**not** with the rest of the books’ feats) gets you a single 2nd-level sor/wiz spell. Since both Magical Training and Precocious Apprentice can only be taken at 1st level, you’ll need to be human (or be using the Flaws variant rules from *Unearthed Arcana*).
- Dragon’s Blood Pool from *Complete Mage* grants you access to a 1st- to 3rd-level spell slot for one year.
- Heighten Spell allows you to shove cantrips into that spell slot.
- Sanctum Spell, also in *Complete Arcane* but with the rest of the feats this time, can let your spells count as one level higher.
- Versatile Spellcaster from *Races of the Dragon* allows you to combine two spells of one level to get a spell of the next level:

  - Combine two cantrips-as-1st-level-spells (due to Sanctum Spell) into a 2nd-level spell slot. Fill using Heighten on one of the cantrips, or (maybe) using the spell you chose for Precocious Apprentice.
  - Combine that with the 2nd-level spell from Precocious Apprentice to get a 3rd-level spell slot. Fill using Heighten.
  - Combine that with the 3rd-level spell from Dragon’s Blood Pool to get a 4th-level spell slot. Fill using Heighten.
- Earth Spell from *Races of Stone* can allow you to Heighten a spell such that it gets a +1 effective spell level above the slot you put it in, so your spell counts as a 5th-level spell in the end.

There are more. See the [Early Entry Handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=11734.0) for more details.

But as you can see, this is very sketchy stuff, and you don’t actually *know* spells of the various levels you have access to; you just get to count lower-level spells as higher level. This is good for e.g. getting into prestige classes, but not very valuable in adventuring most of the time. You only *really* know three cantrips and a single 2nd-level spell, and the tricks break down if you’re not in your sanctum.

If you really want a non-spellcaster with extremely minimal spellcasting, Magical Training plus Precocious Apprentice is probably your best bet. I wouldn’t bother with the rest. Maybe the Dragon’s Blood Pool, but as a magical location you’d have to *find it* first, and that might be tricky.

But really, it’d be much better to play a duskblade or something.

Comment: Once that cantrip's acquired just hunt down the [*book of infinite spells*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/artifacts.htm#bookofInfiniteSpells), and you're all set. (Also, as an alternative, maybe mention cross-class ranks in the skill Use Magic Device?)

Comment: Could a Fighter recive training as a spell caster without changing his fighter class?

Comment: @BulrattheViking Taking a level in a spellcasting class is how the game represents being trained as a spellcaster. The feats KRyan mentioned basically boil down to "I once read a book about it".

Comment: @BulrattheViking The Magical Training feat explicitly says that the character who takes it counts as a 1st-level spellcaster, so yes. Taking the feat also implies that, ya know, you received training; that is the name of the feat, after all.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Actually, Magical Training explicitly says that the character who takes it *is* a spellcaster. And the name does involve *Training*. So it’s more than just having read a book about it. Precocious Apprentice also implies an apprenticeship.

Comment: @KRyan Exactly! Not only having read a book about it, but have a spellbook about it.

Comment: Feats like Mother Cyst can give you access to spells to put in those slots that aren't just cantrips.